# Gitlab 404 when connection to Jira?

Tags: gitlab, jira

I have the latest install of gitlab-ce and Jira Server. I've created an application in gitlab and when I try to connect Jira to gitlab the URL it generates for login/oauth/authorize returns a gitlab 404 page.

Following the guide here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira_development_panel.html

Answer (score 0):

The Jira Development Panel integration feature is "available in GitLab Premium, GitLab.com Silver, and higher tiers" only.

If you want to integrate Jira with GitLab CE (or GitLab FOSS like they want to call it [in the future](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/13304)) you have to stick with the simplistic [Jira GitLab Integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html)

Comment: current issue seems not directly be related to the GitLab edition. Looks like oauth is broken is totally broken in my environment. In my case `https://example.com/login/oauth/authorize` returns 404 for any authorisation (not just DVCS) https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/65327